# Proofs of the three-perpendiculars theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have to prove this theorem in ***three different ways***. I have already proved it **geometricaly** and using **vectors**, but I can not think of any other way.

***Theorem:*** If PQ is perpendicular to a plane XY and if from Q, the foot of the perpendicular, a straight line QR is drawn perpendicular to any straight line ST in the plane, then PR is also perpendicular to ST.

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a reference to what is the three-perpendiculars theorem?

Comment: Theorem: If PQ is perpendicular to a plane XY and if from Q, the foot of the perpendicular, a straight line QR is drawn perpendicular to any straight line ST in the plane, then PR is also perpendicular to ST.

Comment: Include the theorem or a link to it. Most people will ignore your post with a link. Nearly everyone will ignore it with no statement or link.

Comment: I edited it. So @Paul are you going to ignore it ?

Comment: What do you mean with proving it "geometrically"? And how is proof by vectors not geometrical?

Comment: @Wojowu 
Proof: Since LM is parallel to ST and QR perpendicular to ST hence, QR is perpendicular to LM. Again, PQ is perpendicular to the plane XY; hence, it is perpendicular to the line LM. Therefore, LM is perpendicular to both PQ and QR at Q. This implies LM is perpendicular to the plane PQR. Now, ST and LM are parallel and LM is perpendicular to the plane PQR; hence, ST is perpendicular to the plane PQR. Therefore, ST is perpendicular to PR or in other words, PR is perpendicular to ST. This is what imean by geometricaly (sorry but english is not my first language)

Comment: "Using vectors" is a broad statement. I can think of at least three different approaches that "use vectors."

Comment: Can't think of anything that is not a variant of a vector demonstration using dot products.

Comment: @Arkamis I would appreciate if you let me know of **two** of them, so at least one would be different from what I have done.

Comment: Maybe you show your second then someone else can provide a third. Otherwise they may be re-producing what you have.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a point on $ST$ other than $R$. Then

$$PR^2+RA^2=PQ^2+QR^2+RA^2=PQ^2+QA^2=PA^2$$

Therefore, $PR\perp ST$.