# Perpendicular line to a plane ( cube )

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

### The Question

I'm trying to show that $A'C$ perpendicular on plane ($C'BD$). Found that $AB = 6$ and that $A'C'BD$ and $CC'BD$ are both a tetrahedron with the same base ( triangle $C'BD$). Still I can't explain why $A'C$ is perpendicular on plane ($C'BD$).

[image]

### My Understanding

$AE=3\sqrt{6}$

$A'C\perp$(triangle $C' B)$?

I found that $AB=6$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$
A'C'=A'B=A'D,
\quad
CC'=CB=CD
\quad\text{and}\quad
C'B=BD=DC'.
$$

Comment: So I have 2 triangle pyramids with the same base ( triangle C'DB ) . It is enough for conclusion ?

Comment: It all depends on which theorems you already know. If all lateral edges are equal, in a pyramid with regular base, then it is easy to show that the altitude meets the base at its center.

Comment: See this theorem, for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287888/proofs-of-the-three-perpendiculars-theorem